# Compute the max flow of the following network, using the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm.

Tags: graph-theory

> Compute the max flow for the following diagram, using the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm.
>
> [image]

I computed the max flow, using the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm, and I got 14.  However, the capacity of the min cut I found is 16, which does not verify the max-flow/min-cut theorem.  Otherwise, if I did something wrong in finding the min-cut and/or max flow, let me know.  It took me so much hours to work out this problem.

Comment: Can you show us your work? Perhaps we can spot an error in your work.

Answer (score 2):

Max flow is 14.  The cut partition is $\{B, C, D, G\}$ indicated in Green to $\{A, E, F, H\}$ indicated in Purple.   Cut edges are indicated in red.  By [Max-Flow Min-Cut Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem), the simultaneous existence of a cut of capacity 14 and a flow of capacity 14 proves this optimum.

[image: Labeled graph]

You can verify by looking at the validity of the flow by comparing the ingress and egress flow of each vertex.